# design MYSQL database for Multiple page Quiz PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to design MYSQL database for my Quiz PHP script where

One page would have:

Quiz title

Question 1

Question 2

.

.

Question X

Answer 1

Answer 2

.

.

Answer X

---

Second page would have:

Quiz title 2

Question 1

Question 2

.

.

Question X

Answer 1

Answer 2

.

.

Answer X

---

and so on....

Number of questions is variable for all pages, as so as the number of options.

[Picture for clear understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfc0t.jpg)

How I can design the database for such thing? I'm using this basic guide here:
https://www.etutorialspoint.com/index.php/342-how-to-create-a-multiple-choice-quiz-in-php-and-mysql
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you would like to have one page per quiz, so you would need three simple tables:

- Quiz (id, name)
- Question (id, quiz_id, question)
- Answer (id, question_id, correct (1/0))

That would be the basics to get you started, good luck!

Comment: Nice, How I'm supposed to display the data? Better to give example for options, as this would include all

Comment: You would need to select the quiz (based on id) by passing the id to the page, eg. /quiz.php?id=1.  Then for each quiz you would SELECT the questions and answers to display.